# How can I align a bootstrap navbar brand vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The brand is centered until i change it to an img.

I have tried many different ways of fixing it in css, but it wont work.

How can i vertically align this logo? and why doesnt my css work? For some reason, not all of my css styles are being applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Stuff</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css" >

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
<img id="logo" alt="Brand" src="images/logo.jpg" width="40px" height="40px">
</a>
</div>
<div>


<div class="container" id="mynav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#mynav
{
    width: 80%;
}

#logo
{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image: Here is a picture of the problem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only need one `.navbar-header` div, just place the `.navbar-brand` into your [standard](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) `.navbar-header` and adjust the padding for the `.navbar-brand class.`

```
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="https://unsplash.it/40/40/?random">
      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```